# Connecting to wifi in CoreOS?

Tags: wifi, internet, coreos

I can't seem to find very much info on this pretty basic topic for CoreOS: How can I connect my laptop to the internet with wifi? I can't seem to find much of any information for how to connect to the internet with CoreOS, and what little I can find seems to only be for ethernet. And this network does have a password as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incredibly enough, it sounds like this would require determining the driver you need and performing a kernel rebuild.

Brian Harrington (CoreOS contributor) confirms [this here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/coreos-user/aiF2PmuV11g/UkAdNrDNTB4J) and gives instructions on [how to modify CoreOS here](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/sdk-modifying-coreos.html).

Comment: Probably this is before coreos joined red hat. How to do now?

Comment: The links are no longer correct. How to do it now?